# Google Calendar API Java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I want to implement Calendar/Events for one of my applications. So I decided to use Google Calendar API (Java). But I couldn't see the Web part (Front End) of its implementation.  Can any one please help me to get the whole implementation of Google Calendar API (Including Front end).   Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I am not mistaken Google Calendar API allows you to manipulate calendars that stored in Google Calendar. Which means Google Calendar (on Google's servers) takes care of the front end. Which leads me to ask, what are you really trying to accomplish? What is your end game? Welcome to SO by they way.

Comment: @Jacob, I want to embed the Google Calender(Calendar Widget ) into my Website..

Comment: @Erik, it's calendar, not calender

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer and https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth

This enables you to write a web based application that will enable users to log into google and let you view or modify the users calendar

After the authorization (Pretty sequence diagram here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#webserver)
you can use the Google Java APIs to add remove or view calendars or calendaritems or use REST directly from Javascript
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/firstapp#rest

Alternatively you can use the older Calendar Widget for public calendars found here:
https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/cal_sample

Answer (score -1):

**, First of all, you have to create a project on console.developer.google.com and enable calendar API and then you have to set OauthScope and create Credentials then download the credentials.json file and paste into your project then run this program your event will be generated **

```
public class Test {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "GoogleCalenderApi";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = Test.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT)).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
        Event event = new Event();
        event.setSummary("Title of the Event");
        event.setLocation("Location");
        event.setDescription("Something about the event");
        event.setId("event id");
        ArrayList<EventAttendee> attendees = new ArrayList<EventAttendee>();
        attendees.add(new EventAttendee().setEmail("example@gmail.com"));
        attendees.add(new EventAttendee().setEmail("1234@gmail.com"));
        event.setAttendees(attendees);
        String startDate = "2019-10-16 09:00:00";
        Timestamp sDate = Timestamp.valueOf(startDate);
        String endDate = "2019-10-18 18:15:00";
        Timestamp eDate = Timestamp.valueOf(endDate);
        DateTime start = new DateTime(sDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
        DateTime end = new DateTime(eDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));
        EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
                new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 *60),
                new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
        };
        Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
                .setUseDefault(false)
                .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
        event.setReminders(reminders);
        Event createdEvent = service.events().insert("primary", event).execute();
        System.out.println(createdEvent);
        DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Events events = service.events().list("primary")
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .setTimeMin(now)
                .setOrderBy("startTime")
                .setSingleEvents(true)
                .execute();
        List<Event> items = events.getItems();
        if (items.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No upcoming events found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Upcoming events");
            for (Event event1 : items) {
                DateTime start1 = event1.getStart().getDateTime();
                if (start1 == null) {
                    start1 = event1.getStart().getDate();
                }
                System.out.println(event1);
                //System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", event1.getId(), start1);
            }
        }
    }
```